# read an array on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I'm trying to read this array on RoR:

```
> importer_name = [#<RouteImporter id: 1, name: "aa", filename: "aa1", type: "RouteImporter">]
```

I just want to get the filename character "aa1", I tried with importer_name[2] but I didn't get nothing and I don't want 'filename: "aa1"' I just want "aa1", any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give us a little bit more code? How do you create that RouteImporter object for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a Ruby object stored in an array. You can access it like this(If I understand you correctly):

```
importer_name.first.filename
```

Comment: it works! Now I would like to make a require of importer_name.first.filename, but I get this error: cannot load such file -- aa1 RouteImporte inherits from Importer. class Importer < ActiveRecord::Base attr_accessible :name, :filename, :type set_inheritance_column :type end. class RouteImporter < Importer end